# "No module named pip" when attempting to install pyttx3

Tags: python, pip

Command run:

```
PS A:\Python> pip install pyttx3
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "A:\Python Ins\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main  
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "A:\Python Ins\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "A:\Python Ins\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

Comment: Not really an answer but just install Anaconda. It includes all what you may need. You can then use `conda install` to install needed modules. You can use Spyder IDE to make your life easy.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that pip does not get installed by default. First check if pip is installed.

```
python -m ensurepip --default-pip
```

If not, then

```
# Use this command to install pip
python get-pip.py

# If you are using another package manager then use this
python get-pip.py --prefix=/usr/local/
```

If there is an error after this then tell me I will try to fix it.

Comment: Thank you much.
I checked if pip is installed or not then it directly installed a previous version of pip.